# Why isn't the location of my img not changing past 10px?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want an img to follow the mouse, but it doesn't seem to do it.
It stops after it moves 10px. 
I don't know why it's not working. When I set the position of the img to the position of the mouse, it works.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("img").style;
var IE = document.all ? true : false
if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
var tempX;
var tempY;

function getMouseXY(e) {
  if (IE) {
    tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
    tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
  } else {
    tempX = e.pageX;
    tempY = e.pageY;
  }
  
  if (tempX < 0) {
    tempX = 0;
  }
  
  if (tempY < 0) {
    tempY = 0;
  }
  
  document.Show.MouseX.value = tempX;
  document.Show.MouseY.value = tempY;
  return true;
}

document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;
document.onmouseover = update;

elem.left = "0px";
elem.bottom = "0px";
elem.position = "relative";

function update() {
  if (parseInt(elem.left) < (tempX - 10)) {
    elem.left = (parseInt(elem.left) + 1, 10).toString() + "px";
    console.log((parseInt(elem.left) + 1, 10).toString() + "px");
  }
  
  if (parseInt(elem.left) > (tempX - 10)) {
    elem.left = (parseInt(elem.left) - 1, 10).toString() + "px";
    console.log((parseInt(elem.left) - 1, 10).toString() + "px");
  }
  
  if (parseInt(elem.bottom) < (-tempY + 50)) {
    elem.bottom = (parseInt(elem.bottom) + 1, 10).toString() + "px";
    console.log((parseInt(elem.left) + 1, 10).toString() + "px");
  }
  
  if (parseInt(elem.bottom) > (-tempY + 50)) {
    elem.bottom = (parseInt(elem.bottom) - 1, 10).toString() + "px";
    console.log((parseInt(elem.left) + 1, 10).toString() + "px");
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="//placehold.it/20.png">
```

Comment: @llamerr got one for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/ws5ts04k/  (trying to figure it out as well here :))

Comment: No, I'm trying to make it slowly make its way to the mouse.

Comment: I was surprised it moved at all, as that code must be from 1990 or something. You need to read up on today's script and DOM access first, and then update it accordingly, as we can't do all that work for you here.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: @LGSon What's wrong with the code?

Comment: For example this, `document.all`, and this `document.captureEvents`, and this `document.Show.MouseX.value` are either deprecated or invalid.

Comment: document.all is used to check if the browser is running IE. You're right about the others, whoops.